# Display dash html.Div inside dash ag-grid

Tags: python, reactjs, plotly-dash

I am working on `dash` app. I am using `dash Ag-grid` component, to load custom data. For this I am using `cellRenderer` property which is define in `assets/dashAgGridComponentFunctions.js`

```
import dash
from dash import html

# sample content data
data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "First Name": ["Arthur", "Ford", "Zaphod", "Trillian"],
        "Last Name": ["Dent", "Prefect", "Beeblebrox", "Astra"],
    }
)

# sample content title and table
content_title = "some_title"

content_table = dbc.Table.from_dataframe(data, striped=True, bordered=True, hover=True)

# A single content div
content: html.Div = html.Div(
   children=[
       dbc.Row(children=content_title),
       dbc.Row(children=content_table),
   ],
)

# contents is a list of html.Div
contents: list[html.Div] = [content-1, content-2,....]

# sample dataframe
df: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame({"contents": contents}) 

# sample ag-grid
grid: dag.AgGrid = dag.AgGrid(
   id="contents_grid",
   columnDefs=[
        {
           "field": "contents",
           "headerName": "Contents",
           "cellRenderer": "SimpleDivCellRenderer",
        },
    ],
    columnSize="responsiveSizeToFit",
    style={"height": 500, "width": "100%"},
    rowData=df.to_dict("records"),
)
```

I have tried different ways and each time got different error for creating this `custom react` component for dash `html.Div`.(I have very limited knowledge of `javascript` and `react`)

```
# dashAgGridComponentFunctions.js

# way-1
dagcomponentfuncs.SimpleDivCellRenderer = function (props) {
    // const {setData} = props;
    return React.createElement('div', {
        children: props.value,
        // setProps,
        style: {height: '100%', width: '100%'},            
        // className: props.className,
    });
};

# way-2
dagcomponentfuncs.SimpleDivCellRenderer = function (props) {
    // const {setData} = props;
    return React.createElement(window.dash.html.Div, {
        children: props.value,
        // setProps,
        style: {height: '100%', width: '100%'},            
        // className: props.className,
    });
};

# way-3
dagcomponentfuncs.SimpleDivCellRenderer = function (props) {
    // const {setData} = props;
    return React.createElement(window.dash.html.Div, {        
        // setProps,
        style: {height: '100%', width: '100%'},            
        // className: props.className,
    }, props.value);
};
```

Errors like

```
--> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [missing argument]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

--> TypeError: window.html is undefined

--> TypeError: window.dash is undefined
```

What I am missing?